# Error with function 'get_locale_info' in Python3.6

Tags: android, python, cross-compiling, nmake, static-compilation

I am trying the static compilation with **Python3.6.2** and cross-compiling for android. And `nmake` threw following exceptions when running:

```
Python\formatter_unicode.c: In function 'get_locale_info':
Python\formatter_unicode.c:711:53: error: 'struct lconv' has no member named 'decimal_point'
                                          locale_data->decimal_point,
                                                     ^
Python\formatter_unicode.c:716:53: error: 'struct lconv' has no member named 'thousands_sep'
                                          locale_data->thousands_sep,
                                                     ^
Python\formatter_unicode.c:720:44: error: 'struct lconv' has no member named 'grouping'
         locale_info->grouping = locale_data->grouping;
                                            ^
Makefile:14273: recipe for target '.obj\formatter_unicode.obj' failed
nmake: *** [.obj\formatter_unicode.obj] Error 1
```

I've googled a lot but almost nothing practical was found so far. I didn't understand what happened at all although I saw the source code(I just knew a little about C/C++).

Could anyone give some of suggestions to me?

Thank you in advance.